# Certain sadhanas require one to abstain from speech for a period of time. Do scriptures allow written communication in such a case?

Tags: scripture, sadhana

Certain sadhanas require one to abstain from speech for a period of time (say, 40 days). Most householders cannot adhere to this. Do scriptures allow written communication in such a case? If yes, would a text-to-speech system be also permissible?